# Is it possible to disable Chrome energy saver mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a feature I'd like to deploy that will render a webpage borderline unusable when Chrome's energy saver mode is turned on.

Is there any way to toggle off Google Chrome's Energy Saver mode when a user is viewing that page?

Comment: Websites? No. Chrome Browser Extensions? Possibly. SysAdmins with Group Policy? Yes.

Comment: Do you have a source that it isn't possible from a website?

Comment: Chrome doesn't let _any_ website access browser settings. I can't really provide a source for that though (other than the fact Chrome's documented DOM APIs are very-much sandboxed) - otherwise that's like asking for a source to prove it's not possible to run KDE on Windows.

Comment: Gotcha, good context. Thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you seeing Chrome's "Energy saver mode", exactly? To my knowledge, there isn't one: [Chrome already throttles background pages](https://blog.chromium.org/2017/03/reducing-power-consumption-for.html) and there's nothing in Chrome's Settings Search for "energy" either -  Are you maybe thinking of Chrome's recently released Memory-Saver functionality? https://blog.google/products/chrome/new-chrome-features-to-save-battery-and-make-browsing-smoother/

Comment: It's separate from memory saver. Here it is in my Chrome [settings page](https://imgur.com/a/d8qd5ec) and here's the [blurb](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/12929150?visit_id=638238751110984185-1582624541&p=chrome_battery_saver&rd=1#energy_saver&zippy=%2Cturn-energy-saver-on-or-off) in their docs about it

Comment: I also couldn't find much about it when googling, perhaps it's new. Maybe released alongside the memory saver feature.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 114 on Windows 10, and I get zilch: https://imgur.com/a/ZsFYrLc - methinks it's because I'm on a Desktop and not a Laptop?

Comment: Huh, weird. I'm also 114 but on Mac maybe, it's only for Mac's